# Unit Test Retry functionality provided by Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am using the code below to perform exponential retries. I have set the reties to 5. As part of my unit test, I am mocking the response and returning status code 503. However I do not see 5 retries being performed when I use this unit test. What changes should I make to my unit test to validate that session.get has retried 5 times?

```
try:
    max_retries = Retry(total=retries, backoff_factor=5, status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504, 429])
    self.session.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=max_retries))
    # Perform GET request
    response = self.session.get(url, verify=verify)
except Exception as e:
    print(f" Exception occured {e}")
return response
```

**Unit Test**

```
def test_my_function_retries(self):    
    responses.add(responses.GET,
                  'https://requesturl',
                  json={}, status=503)
    request.get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use httpretty to test the retries

```
@httpretty.activate
def test_my_function(self):
    httpretty.register_uri(
        httpretty.GET,
        url,           
        responses=[
            httpretty.Response(
                body='{}',
                status=503,
            ),
        ]
    )

    my_class = MyClass()
    my_class.my_function()
    print(len(httpretty.latest_requests()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer not to make actual calls out to the internet in my tests: the remote service could be down or you might need to run your tests offline. Most importantly you want to run your tests **FAST**, and the network call can slow them down significantly.

I also want to make sure that the retry logic actually makes the retries I expect, and that it can actually succeeds eventually. And do not like the idea of using log messages as a proxy for that.

I could not find a proper solution online, so I'll leave my solution here for posterity, trying to save someone else the hours I've spent trying:

```py
import urllib3
from http.client import HTTPMessage
from unittest.mock import ANY, Mock, patch, call

import requests


def request_with_retry(*args, **kwargs):
    session = requests.Session()
    adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=urllib3.Retry(
        raise_on_status=False,
        total=kwargs.pop("max_retries", 3),
        status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504],  # The HTTP response codes to retry on
        allowed_methods=["HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],  # The HTTP methods to retry on
    ))
    session.mount("https://", adapter)
    session.mount("http://", adapter)
    return session.request(*args, **kwargs)


@patch("urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool._get_conn")
def test_retry_request(getconn_mock):
    getconn_mock.return_value.getresponse.side_effect = [
        Mock(status=500, msg=HTTPMessage()),
        Mock(status=429, msg=HTTPMessage()),
        Mock(status=200, msg=HTTPMessage()),
    ]

    r = request_with_retry("GET", "http://any.url/testme", max_retries=2)
    r.raise_for_status()

    assert getconn_mock.return_value.request.mock_calls == [
        call("GET", "/testme", body=None, headers=ANY),
        call("GET", "/testme", body=None, headers=ANY),
        call("GET", "/testme", body=None, headers=ANY),
    ]
```

*(Note: if you are making several calls to this method, then you might want to initialize the session object only once, not every time you make a request!)*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with retry library you use but it looks like what you need can be found in this library:

https://pypi.org/project/retry/

when I use retries I just extract to functionality I want to perform the retry on to a different method and use the retry decorator like this:

```
from retry import retry

@retry(exceptions=IllegalStateException, tries=2, delay=5)
def flaky_function():
    ...
```

It also keeps the code much cleaner

Comment: Thanks , but I wanted the underlying framework to take care of just http calls and not re-run the entire function. But this definitely seems to be a good tool to have in the toolbox which I will use in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to test the `urllib3.util.retry` Retry package was working with the following pytest code:

```py
# define retrying strategy
retries = Retry(
            total=5,
            backoff_factor=0.4,
            status_forcelist=[429, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 509, 510, 511],
)
# define the session
session = requests.Session()
# Add retries to requests to all https:// addresses
session.mount("https://", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=self.retries))

def test_retry_session(caplog):
    with pytest.raises(requests.exceptions.ConnectionError):
        session.get("https://postman-echo.com/status/200")

    assert "Retry(total=0, " in caplog.records[4].message
    assert "Retry(total=1, " in caplog.records[3].message
    assert "Retry(total=2, " in caplog.records[2].message
    assert "Retry(total=3, " in caplog.records[1].message
    assert "Retry(total=4, " in caplog.records[0].message
```

Comment: Is it possible to catch a `requests.exceptions.RetryError` with a mock ?